# Rails query comparing one col from table Payment and sum of table Transaction

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

There are `Payment` (id, total) and `Transaction` (payment_id, amount) table in our database (simplified for post). Payment's id is in Transaction and they can be joined together if needed.

Here is what we come out with the SQL (simplified somewhat):

```
SELECT * FROM payments a WHERE ABS(a.total) <> (SELECT SUM(d.amount) FROM transactions d WHERE a.id = d.payment_id GROUP BY d.payment_id)
```

I need to assemble a Rails (4.2) query for SQL above, but is stuck with `SELECT sum(d.amount) FROM transactions d WHERE a.id = d.payment_id GROUP BY d.payment_id`.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing subqueries, I'd JOIN and GROUP the two tables:

```
Payment.joins(:transactions).
        group(:id).
        having("ABS(payments.total) <> SUM(transactions.amount)")
```

This relies on the following association between payments and transactions:

```
Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can translate like this:

```
subquery = Transaction.where("transactions.payment_id = payments.id").group(:payment_id).select("SUM(d.amount)").to_sql

Payment.where("ABS(total) <> (#{subquery}))
```

Comment: Need it all in one line. Also the comparison is between the total in payment and the sum of transactions which belongs to the payment. May need payment_id in subquery for comparing late.